# find some attribute in html with regex

Tags: html, regex

I have the following code:

```
<div class="list" style="height: 485px;">
<div id="img_30975054" class="item current" data-pos="1" ctr="{'entity':'thumbs', 'pos':'1'}">
    <img src="link.jpg" data-normal="link-normal.jpg" width="64" height="84"  onerror="imgOnError(this)">
    <em class="arrow"></em>
</div>
<div id="img_28125396" class="item " data-pos="2" ctr="{'entity':'thumbs', 'pos':'2'}">
    <img src="link.jpg" data-normal="link-normal.jpg" width="64" height="84"  onerror="imgOnError(this)">
    <em class="arrow"></em>
</div>
<div id="img_28125398" class="item " data-pos="3" ctr="{'entity':'thumbs', 'pos':'3'}">
    <img src="link.jpg" data-normal="link-normal.jpg" width="64" height="84"  onerror="imgOnError(this)" attribute_id="1451">
    <em class="arrow"></em>
</div>
<div id="img_28125395" class="item " data-pos="4" ctr="{'entity':'thumbs', 'pos':'4'}">
    <img src="link.jpg" data-normal="link-normal.jpg" width="64" height="84"  onerror="imgOnError(this)">
    <em class="arrow"></em>
</div>
<div id="img_28125397" class="item " data-pos="5" ctr="{'entity':'thumbs', 'pos':'5'}">
    <img src="link.jpg" data-normal="link-normal.jpg" width="64" height="84"  onerror="imgOnError(this)" attribute_id="1521">
    <em class="arrow"></em>
</div>
</div>
```

I not know how many img I may have,
but I would to find the value of this attribute `data-normal` for every img.

i have tried

```
data-normal="(.*?)"
```

and this works well but just for first img line.
I want to select only the value for all data-normal without links of img src="".

Comment: Why do you have to use regular expressions (which, admittedly, *can* work) as opposed to parsing the DOM and using DOM methods?

Comment: *which, admittedly, can work* You're being too generous. They cannot work reliably.

Comment: `ctr` is not a valid HTML5 attribute, and your HTML will not validate, if you care.

Comment: Please add your required programming language - `JavaScript`, `PHP`, `Python` ... just to name a few.

Comment: Where does this HTML come from? Is it already in the DOM? Is it a string coming from somewhere?

Comment: if you insist on using regexp for this (which you shouldn't), please show us the code where you invoke the regexp. Is the problem that you have left off the `g` flag on the regexp?

Comment: @torazaburo: yeah, that was the implied disclaimer. I don't like regular expressions much at all (and still regard them as a black, foul magic) but regular expressions and HTML? Ugh, even so: under the right circumstances - and ring-fenced by many, many edge-cases - they *can* work. Just not, as you say, *reliably*.

Comment: i just must select this attribute "data-normal" for selected the url of image  in normal size with regex becouse the program that i use need only collecting regex or collecting xpath

Comment: is difficult to explain.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead?

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('[data-normal]');
```